# Inverse Kinematics on rviz

Tags: rviz, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am recently working on Fetch robot and motion planning and I have run into such a problem:

*Given a serial of pose in work space, the serial of configurations in joint space the IK solver output are not continue (sometime flip).*

I have noticed that when you are dragging the interactive marker on the end-effector in rviz, the joints can always be continue. Does anyone have any idea what kind of IK algorithm rviz is using?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301384/inverse-kinematics-on-rviz/) by [tony chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/37133/tony-chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RVIZ doesn't have any IK internally -- I presume you are using the MoveIt configuration to drag the arm with Interactive Markers? If so, the IK is probably the [KDL plugin](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/tree/kinetic-devel/moveit_kinematics/kdl_kinematics_plugin) from MoveIt. Just a note though: it does not provide any guarantee that the arm won't "flip" -- you're probably just getting lucky since the Fetch has so many continuous rotation joints.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2018-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tony chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/37133/tony-chen/) on 2018-08-25**:
Thank you very much for your help!

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2018-08-25**:
Tony, if that answers your question, please click the checkmark next to my answer to accept the answer.

**Comment by [tony chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/37133/tony-chen/) on 2018-08-27**:
Hi fergs, sorry for asking you again. Do you know any IK plugin in Moveit that can guarantee the continuity of the joint angles? Thanks!

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2018-08-27**:
There really isn't one AFAIK -- that's still an area of active research (for instance, see http://www.roboticsproceedings.org/rss14/p43.html)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-27**:
No guarantee, but `trac_ik` configured with `Distance` solve type will generally return solutions that are "close" to the current pose of the robot. It doesn't give any guarantees, but it will try.

Edit: that is not the same as 'continuity' of course.

**Comment by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on 2021-02-23**:
how can we get that angles